# Can I use Apple Earphones with Mic on Mac Mini?

Tags: audio, mac-mini, microphone, ear-phones

I read on Apple website that Mac mini audio port supports the apple earphones with mic. Does it support the mic as well? Can I use the mic for Audio input on applications like Skype?

I tried plugging it in but the audio input did not work...

**Update**: Here's the apple website where its written that `Support for Apple iPhone headset with microphone` is there. [Mac Mini Specs Page](http://www.apple.com/macmini/specs.html)

**Update**: I think I've got what the problem is. The specs page I referred to above is about the latest Mac Mini. What I have is the Mac Mini mid 2007 model. I checked [its specs](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp7) and there is nothing about support of Apple earphones with mic. I think this is the reason its not working.

Regards

Comment: Where on apple site did you see this statement? I checked but was not able to find it. I didn't find this in the Mac Mini's user guide either.

Comment: @LudoMC - See the update in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot directly plug your headphones into the Audio Input jack and have it work, because, the microphone/button signal rides on the third ring, and the audio input jack only connects the first two. You have to have specially designed hardware to connect to that third ring. This is currently achieved via the Headphone/Audio Output ports of devices.

Only the iPhone/iPod Touch/iPad, 2010 MacBook Pros, and the modern body (smaller height) Mac Minis are the only pieces of hardware I am aware that do. Anything older will not support the microphone/button/volume buttons at all.

Comment: Why whould then they stand explicitly 'Support for Apple iPhone headset with microphone'? Quite strange :-/

Comment: Ok, so, let's get the correct answer, which you might want to give to Dori. Don't plug it into the Audio Input jack, plug it into the Audio Output Jack, then run a program that allows for button control. Say, iTunes (I think?), Keynote (in presentation mode), or something else... Front Row? Click the button, or use the volume controls, tell us if it works. If it does work, I can provide a lot of detailed information as to why, if it doesn't, I can hypothesize something for you.

Comment: @VxJasonV - It doesn't work for iTunes. I tried plugging it in audio output jack.

Comment: @VxJasonV - Plugging in the audio output jack doesn't work for FrontRow as well.

Comment: So I was almost there. Only the modern (shorter) body MacMini supports it. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I have a late 08 macbook 13" that supports it. I have seen 4 pin 3mm to dual 3mm connectors that plug into the headphone and mic separately

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried plugging it into the headphone jack?

Sounds screwy, I know, but I think that's the answer.

Comment: That didn't work.

Comment: @ShiVik - Well, it *would* have worked if your mini supported this feature. See [Can I use iPhone earbuds as a microphone on my MacBook?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3855/can-i-use-iphone-earbuds-as-a-microphone-on-my-macbook) for another example.

Answer (score 2):

If the website or documentation explicitly states that it supports 'Apple Earphones with Mic' or something to that effect while still mentioning the mic, then yes, you should be able to use then as you would on an iPhone, in Skype or whatever. HOWEVER if they don't work in the input port then they will not work at all I didn't think that any other devices except the MBP and the iOS devices worked with them. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and had to use an adapater. I've found [this one](http://www.ixcessory.com/Merchant/merchant.mvc?Screen=PROD&Product_Code=XAS3FPC&Category_Code=XAS&Store_Code=I).
(just for info, I'm not affiliated in any way with the site).

I suppose you can find other brand and stores providing the same type of adapters.

Edit: It seems not to be possible with "normal" headset mic but they state clearly that the Apple headset is compatible. How would it be amplified?

Strange for our mic, I'll have to check at the office how we are using this then. I'm confused now :-/ I know we also have amplified mic and we probably went this way then... Sorry for the wrong info.

Comment: That one converts an iPhone headset to work with a PC—the output from it won't work with a Mac mic input.

Comment: @Dori You're right. I edited my answer. I must have mixed different set-up we made. Sorry.

Comment: It appears that that is compatible with iPhone headsets. What it can't do is successfully connect to a Mac (not the same thing).